# Javascript appendChild(td) works one place, not another

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Consider this HTML (part of a table in a form):

```
<tr id="EnterForRow">
    <td>Entered for</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="enterfor" value "0" checked>Myself
        <input type="radio" name="enterfor" value "1">Someone Else </td>
</tr>
<tr id="PrayerForRow">
    <td>Prayer for </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" name="prayerfor" value="0" checked>Myself
         <input type="radio" name="prayerfor" value="1">Someone Else </td>
</tr>
```

When users click `Someone Else`, I have Javascript to make a new text input box appear on the row.  The Javascript for `PrayerForRow` works but the Javascript for `EnterForRow` does not work.  I can't see any obvious differences.  I think I have been staring at it too long..

This works:

```
var prayforRad =  document.getElementsByName('prayerfor');

for(var i = 0; i < prayforRad.length; i++) 
{
    prayforRad[i].onclick = function() 
    {
        var theValue = radioValue(document.getElementsByName('prayerfor'));
        if (theValue == "1") 
        {
              if (!document.getElementById("pfor")) 
            {
                var newTd = document.createElement("td");
                newTd.setAttribute("id", "pfor");
                var pforRow = document.getElementById("PrayerForRow");
                pforRow.appendChild(newTd);
                newTd.innerHTML = '<td>For: <input type="text" name="PrayFor" id="PrayFor" size="25"></td>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (document.getElementById("pfor")) 
            {
                var pforRow = document.getElementById("PrayerForRow");
                var pf = document.getElementById("pfor");
                pforRow.removeChild(pf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
var enterforRad = document.getElementsByName('enterfor');
for(var j = 0; j < enterforRad.length; j++) 
{
    enterforRad[j].onclick = function() 
    {
        var theValue2 = radioValue(document.getElementsByName('enterfor'));
        if (theValue2 == "1") 
        {
            if (!document.getElementById("efor")) 
            {
                var newTD2 = document.createElement("td");
                newTD2.setAttribute("id", "efor");
                var eforRow = document.getElementById("EnterForRow");
                eforRow.appendChild(newTD2);
                newTD2.innerHTML = '<td>For: <input type="text" name="EntFor" id="EntFor" size="25"></td>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (document.getElementById("efor")) 
            {
                var eforRow = document.getElementById("EnterForRow");
                var ef = document.getElementById("efor");
                eforRow.removeChild(ef);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yh5k8yy5/1/ - is there any error in your console

Comment: You seem to be trying to insert a TD in a TD: `newTD2.innerHTML = '<td>...'`. The result of that will be implementation dependant (browsers may try to correct the error in different ways). TD elements **must** be child nodes of a TR, nothing else.

Comment: Also I would prefer to hide/display a td instead of always creating or removing it

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yh5k8yy5/2/

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the example of your suggestion!  Thanks so much.  I'm learning slowly and your help is really appreciated.

Comment: @ArunPJohny—if you have code to post as an answer, post it here so that it is available as long as this site is available and so others can easily comment on it. The default value for the [*style.display* property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) for table cells in most browsers is *table-cell*, not *block*. When hiding and showing, set to *none* to hide and "" (empty string) to show. That allows the element to adopt its default or inherited style and you don't need to hard code what that might be (as it might be different for different browsers and style rules).

Comment: @RobG thanks for your suggestions... added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td><input type="radio" name="enterfor" value "0" checked>Myself
    <input type="radio" name="enterfor" value "1">Someone Else </td>
```

i think you have lost two "="

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: Well, turns out that WAS the problem.  The value wasn't being returned because I was missing the = between value and "0" and "1".  Oh my.  At least Safari and IE didn't like that!

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comment, it is better to hide/display an existing element than creating those optional elements based on the condition like

```
<tr id="EnterForRow">
    <td>Entered for</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="enterfor" value="0" checked />Myself
        <input type="radio" name="enterfor" value="1" />Someone Else
    </td>
    <td id="efor" style="display: none">For:
        <input type="text" name="EntFor" id="EntFor" size="25" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="PrayerForRow">
    <td>Prayer for</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="prayerfor" value="0" checked />Myself
        <input type="radio" name="prayerfor" value="1" />Someone Else
    </td>
    <td id="pfor" style="display: none">For:
        <input type="text" name="PrayFor" id="PrayFor" size="25" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

then

```
var prayforRad = document.getElementsByName('prayerfor');
for (var i = 0; i < prayforRad.length; i++) {
    prayforRad[i].onclick = function () {
        var theValue = radioValue(document.getElementsByName('prayerfor'));
        var pf = document.getElementById("pfor");
        pf.style.display = theValue == '1' ? '' : 'none'
    }
}

var enterforRad = document.getElementsByName('enterfor');
for (var j = 0; j < enterforRad.length; j++) {
    enterforRad[j].onclick = function () {
        var theValue2 = radioValue(document.getElementsByName('enterfor'));
        var ef = document.getElementById("efor");
        ef.style.display = theValue2 == '1' ? '' : 'none'
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yh5k8yy5/)

Also I would recommend using addEventListener() to add the listener instead of using onclick property